# How to solve the the error: ECONNRESET NODEJS

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, runtime-error, issue-tracking, rabbitmqctl

I´m having problems with my rabbitmq server and my nodejs app.
When I run the `node myfile.js`  returns:

```
2023-11-29 09:30:27.495 [info] [env] Loaded Environment: [prod]
2023-11-29 09:30:27.497 [info] [env] RabbitMQ Instance: [user@amqp://localhost:5672]
2023-11-29 09:30:27.499 [info] [env] Third Party's timeout: [3] sec
2023-11-29 09:30:27.500 [info] [env] -->  <--
2023-11-29 09:30:27.620 [info] [cmd] The RabbitMQ App started on port [8080] at [prod] environment
2023-11-29 09:30:30.838 [info] [app] 55a1493f-306c-4195-8a14-5428eb76b03c|RMQ.PRUEBA|0.68|app=20231129093030834
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on CallbackModel instance at:
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Connection.C.onSocketError (/data/rabbitmq/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:361:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Now if I check the rabbit log found:

```
2023-11-29 09:30:30.924102-06:00 [error] <0.878.0>                                        {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}]}},
2023-11-29 09:30:30.924102-06:00 [error] <0.878.0>                {restart_type,intrinsic},
2023-11-29 09:30:30.924102-06:00 [error] <0.878.0>                {shutdown,300000},
2023-11-29 09:30:30.924102-06:00 [error] <0.878.0>                {child_type,worker}]
```

Please, someone can help me?